# How to create custom order status using an extension / module in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I was wondering whether there is  any way to create custom Orders statuses in Magento. I am developing a Magento Extension in which I have to add some custom order status to magneto orders.

I googled a lot but didn't find any good resources for this.

Could anybody explain how to do this, any resources to refer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets say you want to add "Authorized Payment" status with "authorized" code.

Add the following to config.xml of your module under config/global:

```
    <sales>
        <order>
            <statuses>
                <authorized translate="label">
                    <label>Authorized Payment</label>
                </authorized>
            </statuses>
            <states>
               <authorized translate="label">
                    <label>Authorized Payment</label>
                    <statuses>
                        <authorized default="1"/>
                    </statuses>
                    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>                      
               </authorized>
            </states>
        </order>
    </sales>
```

Earlier it was quite enough but in recent versions (1.5.x.x if I recall correctly) the following bit is also required. Add the following to mysql setup/update file of your extension:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$statusTable        = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status');
$statusStateTable   = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status_state');
$statusLabelTable   = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status_label');

$data = array(
    array('status' => 'authorized', 'label' => 'Authorized Payment')
);
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray($statusTable, array('status', 'label'), $data);

$data = array(
    array('status' => 'authorized', 'state' => 'authorized', 'is_default' => 1)
);
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray($statusStateTable, array('status', 'state', 'is_default'), $data);

?>
```

This technically adds new status to your system. Now you can set it to your order like this:

```
$order->setState('authorized', true, 'Status history message')
      ->save();
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

So that the status is visible at the front is needed:

`<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales/>
            </depends>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>`